# BASH, read first column in file in loop

Tags: bash, awk, cpu

Here is what I am trying to do.  I would like to catch the top 10 cpu consuming PID's and find the program name.  Then display the program name and % CPU in file.

```
CPU_per=$(sar 1 1 | tail -1 | awk '{print 100 - $5}')
echo $CPU_per
if [ $CPU_per -gt 80 ]

    (prstat -u user -n 900 0 1 | grep Type | head -n 10 | awk '{print $1 " " $9}') >> /tmp/PID

for i in $(cat /tmp/PID)
do          
    (awk '{print $1 } | ps -p $PID -o args | tail -1 | cut -d \  -f 2)
```

I would like output to look like

```
Process  %CPU
Program1  5%
Program2  9%
Program3  12%
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. You seem to be posting an odd pseudo-code, which is not recommended. At the least, it is not syntactically correct shell script. You also have a quote missing in the body of the loop, and it isn't clear wy you run the command in a sub-shell. You can request a comma-separated list of PIDs in the `-p` option to `ps`

Comment: I am using Linux, and I think there is no `prstat` command on Linux.. So it might be helpful if you could post the output of `prstat -u user -n 900 0 1`..

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
 echo -e "COMMAND\t\t%CPU"; ps -eo "%c %C%%" --sort pcpu | tail -n10
```